# Quickblox REST API privacy list

Tags: quickblox

Is there any way to work with Privacy lists via REST API? I know that the iOS SDK and now the Android SDK do this, but I need a web solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

Privacy lists API is the XMPP Roster API

Here is a list of all XMPP libraries https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Here is the XMPP documentation http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html

check 5,6,7,8,9 sections